# A single English word equivalent for "逆天"?

Tags: translation

There is most likely not a direct translation for "逆天" which means "breaking common sense", but I'm just curious if there is a single word that can represent that phrase.

Comment: I don't know a single word. But the idea is "challenge an impossible mission". You may come up with a right word.

Comment: Maybe, "godlike"?

Comment: _Formidable_ (as in urban/internet usage) is the closest I can think of, but still not exactly the same metaphor.

Answer (score 2):

OP( overpowered ) is pretty good I think!

Answer (score 1):

It's normally used between teens and the meaning is "pretty great". For example, if you have a great performance in your study, your classmates will say "太逆天了" which means you are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find a eqivalent word in English. Because in different Chinese context, there are different meanings. For example,他的能力逆天了 means "he is very capable" but in some context, it means unconscionable. I (a teacher from han bridge mandarin) hope my explanation can help you.

Comment: I think the OP should have put some more context. As you say, the translation depends on the context. I can't understand why you got a downvote for a perfectly reasonable answer!